# Remove elements from array with elements between times range in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get all elements from an array, given a criteria, where values are between a range of time, without results.

This is an example of source array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [start] => 12:00:00
        [end] => 12:59:00
        [amount] => 6
        [per_hour] => 1
        [group_id] => 5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [start] => 13:00:00
        [end] => 13:59:00
        [amount] => 6
        [per_hour] => 1
        [group_id] => 5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [start] => 14:00:00
        [end] => 14:59:00
        [amount] => 6
        [per_hour] => 1
        [group_id] => 5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [start] => 17:00:00
        [end] => 18:59:00
        [amount] => 4
        [per_hour] => 
        [group_id] => 5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [start] => 05:00:00
        [end] => 08:59:00
        [amount] => 9
        [per_hour] => 
        [group_id] => 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [start] => 11:00:00
        [end] => 11:59:00
        [amount] => 0
        [per_hour] => 1
        [group_id] => 
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [start] => 15:00:00
        [end] => 15:59:00
        [amount] => 0
        [per_hour] => 1
        [group_id] => 
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [start] => 16:00:00
        [end] => 16:59:00
        [amount] => 1
        [per_hour] => 1
        [group_id] => 
    )

)
```

This array contains `start` and `end` values. Some values are, range of times (e.g. 05:00:00 to 08:59:00), and others are an hour range (e.g. 12:00:00 to 12:59:00).

We generate a range, of all 24 hours a day.  We need to determine if one or more records exist in the array, and replace the `amount` field, or delete it from the 24 hours array, if it's range is more than 2 hours:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [start] => 02:00:00
        [end] => 02:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [start] => 03:00:00
        [end] => 03:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [start] => 04:00:00
        [end] => 04:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [start] => 05:00:00
        [end] => 05:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [start] => 06:00:00
        [end] => 06:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [start] => 07:00:00
        [end] => 07:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [start] => 08:00:00
        [end] => 08:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [start] => 09:00:00
        [end] => 09:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [start] => 10:00:00
        [end] => 10:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [start] => 11:00:00
        [end] => 11:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [start] => 12:00:00
        [end] => 12:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [start] => 13:00:00
        [end] => 13:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [start] => 14:00:00
        [end] => 14:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [start] => 15:00:00
        [end] => 15:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [start] => 16:00:00
        [end] => 16:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [start] => 17:00:00
        [end] => 17:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [start] => 18:00:00
        [end] => 18:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [start] => 19:00:00
        [end] => 19:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [start] => 20:00:00
        [end] => 20:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [start] => 21:00:00
        [end] => 21:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [start] => 22:00:00
        [end] => 22:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [start] => 23:00:00
        [end] => 23:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [start] => 00:00:00
        [end] => 00:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

)
```

This is what we need:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [start] => 02:00:00
        [end] => 02:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [start] => 03:00:00
        [end] => 03:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [start] => 04:00:00
        [end] => 04:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [start] => 05:00:00
        [end] => 08:59:00
        [amount] => 9
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [start] => 09:00:00
        [end] => 09:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [start] => 10:00:00
        [end] => 10:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [start] => 11:00:00
        [end] => 11:59:00
        [amount] => 0
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [start] => 12:00:00
        [end] => 12:59:00
        [amount] => 6
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [start] => 13:00:00
        [end] => 13:59:00
        [amount] => 6
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [start] => 14:00:00
        [end] => 14:59:00
        [amount] => 6
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [start] => 15:00:00
        [end] => 15:59:00
        [amount] => 0
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [start] => 16:00:00
        [end] => 16:59:00
        [amount] => 1
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [start] => 17:00:00
        [end] => 18:59:00
        [amount] => 4
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [start] => 19:00:00
        [end] => 19:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [start] => 20:00:00
        [end] => 20:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [start] => 21:00:00
        [end] => 21:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [start] => 22:00:00
        [end] => 22:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [start] => 23:00:00
        [end] => 23:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [start] => 00:00:00
        [end] => 00:59:00
        [amount] => 2
    )

)
```

Comment: not clear please explain what is the logic use to change from to second array for example why [
[3] => Array
    (
        [start] => 05:00:00
        [end] => 08:59:00
        [amount] => 9
    ) amount is 9 and range 4 hours

Comment: Are the time ranges always start at 00:00 of an hour an end at 59:00 of an hour?

Comment: What did you tried ? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MohdAlomar, these are two different arrays. The first had information that we want to change or replace better in the second. In the second, the quantity is usually 2 but we want to replace it with the quantity value of the first and join it with the start and end fields. The result must be the third array

Comment: @KoalaYeung, yes, yes sir. Originally we made a query in range of hours in mysql, but it change with range for example, between 5:00 am and 9:00 am only we allow x rides in that range. Note this could change the default amount

Answer (score 0):

You can take the solution below as guide, the solution is naive and time complexity is  around n^2 but because in is small I think it is ok to use it.

The idea to build the third array one by one starting from the first array then add the missing items later.

```
<?php
// this is our first array 
$firstArray = [ 
    ['start' => '12:00:00', 'end' => '12:59:00', 'amount' => 6, 'per_hour' => 1, 'group_id' => 5],
    ['start' => '13:00:00', 'end' => '13:59:00', 'amount' => 6, 'per_hour' => 1, 'group_id' => 5],
    ['start' => '14:00:00', 'end' => '14:59:00', 'amount' => 6, 'per_hour' => 1, 'group_id' => 5],
    ['start' => '17:00:00', 'end' => '18:59:00', 'amount' => 4, 'per_hour' => 1, 'group_id' => 5],
    ['start' => '05:00:00', 'end' => '08:59:00', 'amount' => 9, 'per_hour' => 1, 'group_id' => 5],
    ['start' => '11:00:00', 'end' => '11:59:00', 'amount' => 0, 'per_hour' => 1, 'group_id' => 5],
    ['start' => '15:00:00', 'end' => '15:59:00', 'amount' => 0, 'per_hour' => 1, 'group_id' => 5],
    ['start' => '16:00:00', 'end' => '16:59:00', 'amount' => 1, 'per_hour' => 1, 'group_id' => 5],
];

// this is our second array
$secondArray = [ 
    ['start' => '02:00:00', 'end' => '02:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '03:00:00', 'end' => '03:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '04:00:00', 'end' => '04:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '05:00:00', 'end' => '05:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '06:00:00', 'end' => '06:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '07:00:00', 'end' => '07:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '08:00:00', 'end' => '08:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '09:00:00', 'end' => '09:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '10:00:00', 'end' => '10:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '11:00:00', 'end' => '11:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '12:00:00', 'end' => '12:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '13:00:00', 'end' => '13:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '14:00:00', 'end' => '14:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '15:00:00', 'end' => '15:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '16:00:00', 'end' => '16:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '17:00:00', 'end' => '17:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '18:00:00', 'end' => '18:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '19:00:00', 'end' => '19:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '20:00:00', 'end' => '20:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '21:00:00', 'end' => '21:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '22:00:00', 'end' => '22:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '23:00:00', 'end' => '23:59:00', 'amount' => 2],
    ['start' => '00:00:00', 'end' => '00:59:00', 'amount' => 2],

];

//this is the generated array that have amount from firstArray if time slot is found and will comine all slot if in range, 
$thirdArray = [];



//your firstArray is the most imporatant but not sorted so we will start the loop in it. 

foreach ($firstArray as $timeSlot) {
    $first_array_start_time =  (int)str_replace('-', '', $timeSlot['start']);
    $first_array_end_time =  (int)str_replace('-', '', $timeSlot['end']);
    foreach ($secondArray as &$secondTimeSlot) {
        //by refrence because I want to update it 
        if(!isset($secondTimeSlot['found']))
            $second_array_start_time =  (int)str_replace('-', '', $secondTimeSlot['start']);
            $second_array_end_time =  (int)str_replace('-', '', $secondTimeSlot['end']);
            if($first_array_start_time <=  $second_array_start_time &&  $first_array_end_time >= $second_array_end_time)
            {
                //it is within the range
                $secondTimeSlot['found'] = true;

            }
    }
    $thirdArray[] = ['start' => $timeSlot['start'], 'end' => $timeSlot['end'], 'amount' => $timeSlot['amount']];
}
unset($secondTimeSlot);
foreach ($secondArray as $secondTimeSlot) {
    if(!isset($secondTimeSlot['found']))
    {
        $thirdArray[] = ['start' => $secondTimeSlot['start'], 'end' => $secondTimeSlot['end'], 'amount' => $secondTimeSlot['amount']];
    }   
}

$starts = array_column($thirdArray, 'start');
array_multisort($starts, SORT_ASC, $thirdArray);

var_dump($thirdArray);
```